# How to save data into mysql database in django?

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I am trying to save form data in the mysql database for car rental information but it not stored proparly but so i am getting error.for this i tried following code.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class car_info(models.Model):

   location = models.CharField(max_length=400)
   from_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
   to = models.CharField(max_length=400)
   date = models.DateField()
   time = models.TimeField()
   def __str__(self):
      return ' '.join([
        self. ordering,

    ])
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from dem.models import car_info

def demo(request):

   n = request.POST.get("loc_id", ' ')
   ad = request.POST.get("from_id", ' ')
   em = request.POST.get("to_id", ' ')
   m = request.POST.get("date_id", ' ')
   ch_id = request.POST.getlist("tm_id" ,' ')

#search = car_info(Name)
queryset1 = car_info(location=n, from_id=ad, to=em, date=m, time=ch_id)

queryset1.save()
data = {
    'queryset1': queryset1,

}

return render(request, 'home.html', data)
```

home.html

```
 <body>
 <form action="/link/" id="frm_id" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <h3><marquee>Car rental</marquee></h3>
 <div>
 <table class="center">
 <tr>
 <td>Location
    <select name="loc_id"><option value='pune'>Pune</option>

    </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>From
    <select name="from_id"><option value='Akurdi'>Akurdi</option>
        <option value='Pashan'>Pashan</option>
        <option value='Baner'>Baner</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>To
    <select name="to_id"><option value='Akurdi'>Akurdi</option>
        <option value='Pashan'>Pashan</option>
        <option value='Baner'>Baner</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Date
    <input type="date" name="date_id">


 </td>
 <td>Time
    <input type="time" name="tm_id">

 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" value="book a Car" name="sb_id">
 </td>

 </table>
 </div>
 </form>
```

So what can i do changes in the above code so the data will save in the database ?
and where i go wrong?

getting error:

```
exception type:TypeError
exception value:expected string or buffer
```

i think this error should on:

```
 queryset1.save()
```

Comment: By default, the `demo` view is called in `GET`mode. Now, once the form is submitted, it is a `POST` -  All the save to database logic should go in `if request.method == "POST":`

Comment: Your code in views, below demo(), isn't indented properly - is that a copy-paste problem? Also paste the error next time :)

Comment: thanks karthikr.....but its not working....

Comment: "It is not working" is a very vague response buddy.. You need to be more specific if you want people to help you out better. Moreover, I just gave you a general direction to build on top of. It was not the solution.

Comment: You should use a ModelForm instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/